# Firebase returns nil when fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had a problem with fetching data, seems to be working now, but instead of observing .childAdded, i need to observe value.

My Current code function is:

```
    func fetchJobs() {
ref.child("jobposts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    
    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]  else { return}
    
    var job = JobData()
    
    job.title = (dictionary["title"] as! String) <-- Error in any of the job.*
    job.company = (dictionary["company"] as! String)
    job.city = (dictionary["city"] as! String)
    job.salary = (dictionary["salary"] as! String)
    job.creator = (dictionary["creator"] as! String)
    
    self.jobs.append(job)
    
}
}
```

When i change .observe(.childAdded) to .observe(.value) i get an error :

```
 Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Using print(dictionary) prints all the documents, maybe i need to map them somehow? Thank you in advance

Comment: "Any ideas what could cause this?"  What is Firebsse?  Which service are you referring to?

Comment: No, don't use .value as with every change within the observed node, the entire node is reloaded and you don't want that. You want .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved to get find-grained updates so you can update your tableView dataSource and UI. See my comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you observe a .value event for a list of nodes, you need to loop over `snapshot.children` to get the individual nodes. From the documentation on [listening for value events for lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
_commentsRef.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
}
```

The `...` is where your current code inside the `.childAdded` listener goes.

Comment: Frank, Thank you! Seems to be fetching data now. The only problem, that when i manually change data in the database, the app appends a new listing and doesn't just edit the values of the old one. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Sure thing! Do you by any chance know the exact command to clear the current data?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+clear+a+list+in+swift?

Comment: @ToothFairy To add on to this answer. The problem is you're only using .childAdded which will notify your app only when children are added. While clearing the array is fine, you probably want more fine-grained control; if a child is changed, for example, you wouldn't need to clear the list - just update the one that was changed. That's done through .childChanged events as well as .childRemoved events. So in essence, when a child is changed, your app will receive an event containing the changed data, include the node key. You can then locate that node in your array and update it (and the UI).